# How to use LIKE in a query to find multiple words?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like, textmatching

I have a cust table

```
id  name           class    mark

1   John Deo Matt   Four    75
2   Max Ruin        Three   85
3   Arnold          Three   55
4   Krish Star HN   Four    60
5   John Mike       Four    60
6   Alex John       Four    55
```

I would like to search for a customer which might be given as `John Matt` without the `deo` string. How to use a LIKE condition for this?

```
SELECT * FROM cust WHERE name LIKE '%John Matt%'
```

The result should fetch the row 1.

what if the search string is `Matt Deo` or `john`

The above can't be implemented when trying to find an exact name. How can I make the LIKE query to fetch the customer even if 2 strings are given?

Comment: % is a wildcard. so where name like 'John%Matt' will match 'John something Matt'

Comment: @Rene But what if `Matt Deo` has to search ?

Comment: `select * from cust where name Like '%John%Matt%' ;` And don't forget that Oracle will check the words case (case sensitive).

Comment: @RubahMalam Does not work if `Like '%Matt%John%' `

Comment: Of course you can always provide examples that don't work. However, the answers given do work given your original question. Maybe you have to update your question and better specify your requirements.

Comment: You will need some help from your programming language. First, extract the words into single word such as *John,Mat,Doe* then `where name like '%john%' or name like '%mat%'...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the pattern to be matched is

```
string1<space>anything<space>string2
```

you can write:

```
like string1||' % '||string2
```

Comment: what if search string given `Matt Deo`

Comment: See if you can rewrite my statement to suit your needs. You can always add an or ... to match string1||' '||string2.

Answer (score 1):

Why not this

```
select * from cust where name Like 'John%Matt' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT *
   FROM custtable
  WHERE upper(NAME) LIKE '%' || upper(:first_word) || '%'
    AND upper(NAME) LIKE '%' || upper(:second_word) || '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Must you use `LIKE`? Oracle has plenty of more powerful search options.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/content.htm#sthref2643

I'd look at those.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need REGEXP_LIKE( ):

```
SQL> with tbl(name) as (
      select 'John Deo Matt' from dual
    )
    select name
    from tbl
    where regexp_like(name, 'matt|deo', 'i');

NAME
-------------
John Deo Matt

SQL>
```

Here the regex string specifies name contains 'matt' OR 'deo' and the 'i' means its case-insensitive.  The order of the names does not matter.